# How do I use docker-compose.yml with Tensorflow + Jupyter Notebook + GPU

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, gpu

I've been using tensorflow docker images to run Tensorflow with GPU which works fine. For example, I just write this command with the `--gpus all` flag.

`docker run -it --rm --gpus all -v $PWD:/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888  tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.2-gpu-py3-jupyter`

I would like to use docker-compose instead and was trying to follow the steps from Docker's enabling GPU access site [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/) and can't get it to work with the jupyter notebook GPU Tensorflow images. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Below is my docker-compose.yml code which I use to run the command `docker-compose up`

```
#version: "3.3"

services:
  jupyter:  # you can change this to whatever you want.
    container_name: computer-vison
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.2-gpu-py3-jupyter
    volumes:
      - "./:/tf/notebooks"
    ports:
     - "8888:8888"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          -  driver: nvidia
            count: all
            capabilities: [gpu]
```

The error I get is

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 14, column 11
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 16, column 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like an indentation error at the line with `count` , try this:

```yaml
#version: "3.3"

services:
  jupyter:  # you can change this to whatever you want.
    container_name: computer-vison
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.2-gpu-py3-jupyter
    volumes:
      - "./:/tf/notebooks"
    ports:
     - "8888:8888"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          -  driver: nvidia
             count: all
             capabilities: [gpu]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! You wouldn't happen to know why I have to put the "-" symbol?